# On delete actions when a table has a 2 foreign key from 2 different tables

Tags: sql, database, foreign-keys, constraints

I have a table let's say `table3` and it contains two foreign keys, each one referencing a different table. I want to learn that, could I define two different `ON DELETE` action for them.

Let me explain it via an example.

```
create table table3 (
    ID varchar(255),
    Name varchar(255),
    primary key(ID,Name),
    foreign key(ID) References user(id),
    foreign key(Name) References shops(StoreName)
       on update cascade
       on delete cascade // I want to cascade table if id is deleted
       on delete no actions); // and do not allowed  if StoreName is deleted.
```

Is there anyone to help me ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I totally understand what you're trying to do - but if you want to have `ON DELETE CASCADE` on the fk reference to the `User` table, and `ON DELETE NO ACTIONS` on the fk reference to the `Shops` table, you need to use this T-SQL:

```
create table table3 (
    ID varchar(255),
    Name varchar(255),
    primary key(ID,Name),

    foreign key(ID) References user(id)
       on delete cascade,    // I want to cascade table if id is deleted        

    foreign key(Name) References shops(StoreName)
       on update cascade
       on delete no actions); // and do not allowed  if StoreName is deleted.
```

You need to specify the `ON DELETE ....` action right with your `foreign key` definition

Comment: thats what I wanted to ask. Thanks a lot